# Load external TinyMCE plugin using jQuery TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I use the TinyMCE jQuery plugin to assign TinyMCE to an input field (on document ready).
Now, I wrote a plugin for TinyMCE and want to load it.
The problem is, since the jQuery plugin loads the TinyMCE js file only when it's required, I can't just include my plugin js file since the "tinymce" object isn't loaded at this point.
How can I load my plugin at the right time?

Comment: One quick hack would be adding your plugin to the same file of the tinymce one.

Answer (score 3):

Found it: There is a configuration option called `external_plugins`

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#external_plugins

Comment: Just to update link: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#external_plugins